# Java connection with Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, url, connection

I want to create an App, it can show the newest movies datas, with trailers from Movie Database

I try to connect url, with threads to search the trailers. But its load only the first 38 connect succes, but i need 60. I have no idea why.
Is anyone has?

P.S.: I am sorry my English

```
    private Thread loadTrailers = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        int counter = 0;
        String str = new String("");
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try { // try open source site
            URL url = new URL("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+id+"/videos?api_key="+myApikey);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));  // problem with openConnection()
            if(br != null){
                if((str = br.readLine()) != null){
                    String[] moviedatas = str.split("\"id\"");
                    for(int i = 1; i < moviedatas.length && counter < 3;++i){
                        Pattern isTrailer = Pattern.compile(".*Trailer.*");
                        Matcher matc_tr = isTrailer.matcher(moviedatas[i]);
                        if(matc_tr.matches()){
                            Pattern getKey = Pattern.compile(".*key\":\"(.*)\",\"name.*");
                            Matcher key = getKey.matcher(moviedatas[i]);
                            if(key.matches()){
                                links.add("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+key.group(1));
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid URL!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Connection failed from trailers.");
        } finally {
            try {
                if(br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("File close not success.");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Post code how do you  create & invoke your threads.

Comment: The loadTrailers.start() calld in the Movie constructor. So when create a movie start download the picture and the trailers links both with treads.

Comment: `public Movie(String title, String language, String poster, String overview, String isadult, String rate, String date, String id) {

  this.title = new String(title);

  this.language = new String(language);

  this.overview = new String(overview);

  if(isadult.equals("false")){

   this.isadult = false;

  } else {

   this.isadult = true;

  }

  this.rate = Double.parseDouble(rate);

  this.date = date;

  this.id = id;

  this._poster_ = poster;

  loadImage.start();

  loadTrailers.start();

 }`

Comment: There are so many places this could possibly go wrong... Are you even sure that all the responses are valid?

Comment: Unfortunatelly yes, and as i said it runs perfectly in the first 38 times, onli the last 22 times it says "Connection failed from trailers" when try url.openConnection()

Comment: Could you paste the error message to your question also?